# How to create a git pull --rebase conflict for testcase?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull, gitpython, git-merge-conflict

I would like to create a test case that solves a rebase conflict, but first I need a way to cause the rebase conflict when doing a `git pull --rebase`.

Is there a programmatic way of creating a rebase conflict scenario?

The test will be for a GitPython program.

Comment: By *rebase conflict* do you mean a *merge conflict*, that makes the rebase stop and require you to clean up the mess and run `git rebase --continue`?

Comment: Yes, I wan't to run into that scenario where you are in the rebase process and need to solve merge conflicts and continue.

Comment: OK, then PapyDanone's answer will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quickly create a rebase conflict, you can do the following:

1. modify a file, commit and push to the remote repository
2. make a change to the same file on the same line
3. *amend* the last commit with `git commit -a --amend -C HEAD`. The HEAD commit hash has now changed
4. run `git pull --rebase`

You'll end up with a conflict at the line you modified.

To clean up: you may want to `git reset --hard origin/[your-branch]` after your test to get back to step 1.